# JPA at Query named parameters issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In the following query if I try to run the query by giving for example "488" as age. This JPA query considers it 4 and return result accordingly which is wrong. I do not know why JPA is trimming 2nd and third characters in this case. Any tips would be great. I would like to return all products where age is greater than 488 (example). If I replace greater than (>) sign with equal than JPA does not trim any characters and return all products where age is "488".

```
@Query("SELECT new com.model.Result(am.product, am.age)"
            + "FROM Table am WHERE am.age > :age")
    List<Result> queryResult(@Param("age") String age );
```

Comment: What is the type of `Table.am`? You are comparing it with String, so it will compare lexicographically, meaning `"5" > "488"` is true. Try changing the type of the `age` argument to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that age is number type. Then you must also use the same type. For example Integer

```
@Query("SELECT new com.model.Result(am.product, am.age)"
        + "FROM Table am WHERE am.age > :age")
List<Result> queryResult(@Param("age") int age );
```

Comment: Age is Varchar in database.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql as database

Comment: The question is why are you storing numeric values in a varchar. That's the main problem because mysql compares the strings not the numeric value. You would have to cast the age to a number but this is not possible with JPA Query

Comment: You would need to use a native SQL query with a cast like this CAST(age AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing here is lexical comparison. When you want the strings to be interpreted as numbers to be able to compare numerically, you will have to cast:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.model.Result(am.product, am.age)"
        + "FROM Table am WHERE cast(am.age as integer) > :age")
List<Result> queryResult(@Param("age") int age);
```